# Strange values in a lambda returning initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, initializer-list

Consider this **C++11** code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <initializer_list>


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    enum Switch {
        Switch_1,
        Switch_2,
        Switch_3,
        Switch_XXXX,
    };

    int foo_1 = 1;
    int foo_2 = 2;
    int foo_3 = 3;
    int foo_4 = 4;
    int foo_5 = 5;
    int foo_6 = 6;
    int foo_7 = 7;

    auto get_foos = [=] (Switch ss) -> std::initializer_list<int> {
        switch (ss) {
            case Switch_1:
                return {foo_1, foo_2, foo_3};
            case Switch_2:
                return {foo_4, foo_5};
            case Switch_3:
                return {foo_6, foo_7};
            default:
                throw std::logic_error("invalid switch");
        }
    };

    std::set<int> foos = get_foos(Switch_1);
    for (auto && foo : foos) {
        std::cout << foo << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Whatever compiler I try, all seem to handle it incorrectly. This makes me think that I am doing something wrong rather than it's a common bug across multiple compilers.

**clang 3.5** output:

```
-1078533848 -1078533752 134518134
```

**gcc 4.8.2** output:

```
-1078845996 -1078845984 3
```

**gcc 4.8.3** output (compiled on http://www.tutorialspoint.com):

```
1 2 267998238
```

**gcc (unknown version)** output (compiled on http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com)

```
-1785083736 0 6297428
```

The problem seems to be caused by using `std::initializer_list<int>` as a return value of lambda. When changing lambda definition to `[=] (Switch ss) -> std::set<int> {...}` returned values are correct.

Please, help me solve this mystery.

Comment: As I point out in my answer below it is ironic that in the final proposal for `initializer_list` points out this exact scenario and dismisses it as an unlikely issue.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list

> The underlying array is not guaranteed to exist after the lifetime of the original initializer list object has ended. The storage for std::initializer_list is unspecified (i.e. it could be automatic, temporary, or static read-only memory, depending on the situation).

I don't think the initializer list is copy-constructable. `std::set` and other containers are. Basically it looks like your code behaves similar to "returning a reference to a temporary".

C++14 has something slightly different to say about the underlying storage - extending *its* lifetime - but that does not fix anything having to do with the lifetime of the `initializer_list` object, let alone copies thereof. Hence, the issue remains, even in C++14.

> The underlying array is a temporary array, in which each element is copy-initialized (except that narrowing conversions are invalid) from the corresponding element of the original initializer list. The lifetime of the underlying array is the same as any other temporary object, **except that initializing an initializer_list object from the array extends the lifetime of the array exactly like binding a reference to a temporary** (with the same exceptions, such as for initializing a non-static class member). The underlying array may be allocated in read-only memory.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what happens. The init list is backed by a stack-allocated array, and that array goes poof when the lambda returns.

Comment: Strange thing is that no compiler generates a single warning. Looks like it's an overlook in a standard, isn't it? Seems like since c++14 the behavior is changed and my code snippet becomes valid.

Comment: It's not syntactically wrong, only at runtime. If a user defined data type (which std::initializer_list is) does not have a copy c'tor and one is required for the syntactical construct, it will generate one for you, even if it's the wrong thing to do. std::initializer_list could usefully have disabled its copy constructor, in which case the compiler _would_ have complained about your code indeed.

Comment: `initializer_list` is copyable (hence this compiles) but it only performs a shallow copy. Frankly I find this to be an awful C++11 "feature". Fortunately, yes, this is fixed in C++14, in which the lifetime of the underlying array is extended during a copy of the `initializer_list`, much like it would if you bound it to a reference. _Unfortunately_, GCC 4.9.2 in C++14 mode [still gets it wrong](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8c5cff3eefab374). I haven't tested with HEAD.

Comment: That is certainly very true. It is not a very useful feature ;-)

Comment: GCC 5.0.0 20150202 (experimental) in C++1y mode [also fails](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Jj55WxUQaDymtSSu). Slightly concerned now that I'm missing something.

Comment: Actually, it still doesn't say anything about what happens if the initializer list is copied. My initial answer was based on the fact that std::initializer_list does not seem to *have* a copy constructor defined.

Comment: *"Fortunately, this 'oversight' could/should have been fixed in C++14"*, which sentence of the paragraph you pasted indicate this *should* be fixed and that this was an *oversight*?: *"The lifetime of the underlying array is the **same as any other temporary object**, except that initializing an initializer_list object from the array extends the lifetime of the array exactly **like binding a reference to a temporary**"*. Creating a reference initialized by other reference-type variable doesn't extend the lifetime of the original temporary until the *last* reference exists. Array is a temporary

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the array's lifetime is extended until the lifetime of the `initializer_list` object it is used to initialize ends; but that `initializer_list` object is the temporary return value of the lambda, whose lifetime ends at the `;`. (That's not even counting the fact that the array in the question is "bound" in an return statement, so normally you don't get any lifetime extension at all.)

Comment: @PiotrS. even though  "The lifetime of the underlying array is the same as any other temporary object..." fully specifies a lifetime expectation, the _oversight_ may be the lack of considerations for use cases like this, where without such detailed knowledge, one might quite intuitively expect the copy behavior as indicated by the question. At least that is my interpretation of how this could be regarded an oversight. In situations like this, even though the behaviour is fully specified, in most cases, for most people it becomes identified and regarded as a "gotcha" or "quirk" of the standard.

Comment: The oversight is that `initializer_list` is, in general, very poorly specified for obvious cases like this.

Answer (score 16):

The problem is that you are referencing an object that no longer exists and therefore you are invoking [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). `initializer_list` seems underspecified in the [C++11 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), there are no normative sections that actually specify this behavior. Although there are plenty of notes that indicate this will not work and in general although notes are not normative if they don't conflict with the normative text they are strongly indicative.

If we go to section `18.9` *Initializer lists* it has a note which says:

> Copying an initializer list does not copy the underlying elements.

and in section `8.5.4` we have the following examples:

```
typedef std::complex<double> cmplx;
std::vector<cmplx> v1 = { 1, 2, 3 };

void f() {
    std::vector<cmplx> v2{ 1, 2, 3 };
    std::initializer_list<int> i3 = { 1, 2, 3 };
}
```

with the following notes:

> For v1 and v2, the initializer_list object and array created for { 1, 2, 3 } have full-expression
>   lifetime. For i3, the initializer_list object and array have automatic lifetime.

These notes are consistent with the [initializer_list proposal: N2215](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2215.pdf) which gives the following example:

```
std::vector<double> v = {1, 2, 3.14};
```

and says:

> Now add `vector(initializer_list<E>)` to `vector<E>` as shown above. Now,
>   the example works. The initializer list {1, 2, 3.14} is interpreted as
>   a temporary constructed like this:
>
> ```
> const double temp[] = {double(1), double(2), 3.14 } ;
> initializer_list<double> tmp(temp,
> sizeof(temp)/sizeof(double));
> vector<double> v(tmp);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> Note that an initializer_list is a small object (probably two words),
>   so passing it by value makes sense. Passing by value also simplifies
>   inlining of begin() and end() and constant expression evaluation of
>   size().
>
> An initializer_list s will be created by the compiler, but can be
>   copied by users. Think of it as a pair of pointers.

The `initializer_list` in this case just holds pointers to an automatic variable which will not exist after exiting the scope.

**Update**

I just realized the proposal actually points out this *misuse scenario*:

> One implication is that an initializer_list is “ pointer like” in that
>   it behaves like a pointer in respect to the underlying array. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> int * f(int a)
> { 
>    int* p = &a;
>    return p; //bug waiting to happen
> }
>
> initializer_list<int> g(int a, int b, int c)
> {
>    initializer_list<int> v = { a, b, c };
>    return v; // bug waiting to happen
> }
> ```
>
> **It actually takes a minor amount of ingenuity to misuse an
>   initializer_list this way. In particular, variables of type
>   initializer_list are going to be rare**.

I find the last statement(*emphasis mine*) particularly ironic.

**Update 2**

So [defect report 1290](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1290) fixes the normative wording and so it now covers this behavior, although the copy case could be more explicit. It says:

> A question has arisen over expected behavior when an initializer_list
>   is a non-static data member of a class. Initialization of an
>   initializer_list is defined in terms of construction from an
>   implicitly allocated array whose lifetime "is the same as that of the
>   initializer_list object". That would mean that the array needs to live
>   as long as the initializer_list does, which would on the face of it
>   appear to require the array to be stored in something like a
>   std::unique_ptr within the same class (if the member is
>   initialized in this manner).
>
> It would be surprising if that was the intent, but it would make
>   initializer_list usable in this context.

The resolution fixes the wording and we can find the new wording in the [N3485 version of the draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf). So section `8.5.4` *[dcl.init.list]* now says:

> The array has the same lifetime as any other temporary object (12.2),
>   except that initializing an initializer_- list object from the array
>   extends the lifetime of the array exactly like binding a reference to
>   a temporary.

and `12.2` *[class.temporary]* says:

> The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function
>   return statement (6.6.3) is not extended; the temporary is destroyed
>   at the end of the full-expression in the return statement.

Comment: @dyp I saw you left a comment that you since removed. If you see a normative section that specifies the lifetime and copying like the notes do, please let me know.

Comment: I think the binding of a temporary array to a reference does specify the lifetime (in [dcl.init.list]/6). This also agrees with the strange fact that you may not have `constexpr auto x = {1,2};` locally, but `constexpr static auto x = {1,2};`: the lifetime of the temporary array in the first example is extended to the lifetime of an automatic object, and in the second to a static object. Being an object of static storage duration, it is legal to deal with addresses.

Comment: But it's not very explicit, and the results are rather surprising IMHO. I'd guess that writing it explicitly like `template<class T> using id = T; auto&& il = id<int[]>{1, 2};` might have been a better idea. That array is noncopyable, so you see the weird reference semantics when you try to pass it to or try to return it from a function.

Comment: As far as I understand it, the lifetime is similar to [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a48ef19d1c02dfc1), with the sole difference that the lifetime is also extended when you write `initializer_list<int> x = initializer_list<int>{1,2,3};` (which is really more like the `id<int[]>` example above, but the reference is hidden inside `intializer_list`)

Comment: @dyp yes paragraph does say the lifetime is the same as an array but that does not cover copying which the non-normative note in `18.9` covers. So I don't think that is enough to prove it won't work, or at least it is no specific enough for me. Considering the last line I highlight from the proposal this just seems like an oversight. The proposers felt this was obvious but clearly it is not.

Comment: Ironically it is sometimes useful to be able to pass along `std::initializer_list` since all the containers in the Standard Lib have convenient initialization from it as well as `insert()` method. I am really sad that no compiler had pointed out misuse as a warning.

Comment: @dyp found a defect report that fixes the normative wording from `N3337`

Comment: Actually, I did read a recent post-N4296 draft, but that section only specifies the lifetime of the temporary array used to initialize the `intializer_list` from a braced-init-list; it does not seem to specify the semantics of the copy ctor, as you said in your earlier response.

Answer (score 2):

So, `initializer_list`s do not extend the lifetime of their referenced array when they are themselves copied or moved to the result of the copy/move.  This makes returning them problematic.  (they do extend the lifetime of the referenced array to their own lifetime, but this extension is not transitive over elision or copies of the list).

To fix this problem, store the data, and manage its lifetime manually:

```
template<size_t size, class T>
std::array<T, size> partial_array( T const* begin, T const* end ) {
  std::array<T, size> retval;
  size_t delta = (std::min)( size, end-begin );
  end = begin+delta;
  std::copy( begin, end, retval.begin() );
  return retval;
}
template<class T, size_t max_size>
struct capped_array {
  std::array<T, max_size> storage;
  size_t used = 0;
  template<size_t osize, class=std::enable_if_t< (size<=max_size) >>
  capped_array( std::array<T, osize> const& rhs ):
    capped_array( rhs.data(), rhs.data()+osize )
  {}
  template<size_t osize, class=std::enable_if_t< (size<=max_size) >>
  capped_array( capped_array<T, osize> const& rhs ):
    capped_array( rhs.data(), rhs.data()+rhs.used )
  {}
  capped_array(capped_array const& o)=default;
  capped_array(capped_array & o)=default;
  capped_array(capped_array && o)=default;
  capped_array(capped_array const&& o)=default;
  capped_array& operator=(capped_array const& o)=default;
  capped_array& operator=(capped_array & o)=default;
  capped_array& operator=(capped_array && o)=default;
  capped_array& operator=(capped_array const&& o)=default;

  // finish-start MUST be less than max_size, or we will truncate
  capped_array( T const* start, T const* finish ):
    storage( partial_array(start, finish) ),
    used((std::min)(finish-start, size))
  {}
  T* begin() { return storage.data(); }
  T* end() { return storage.data()+used; }
  T const* begin() const { return storage.data(); }
  T const* end() const { return storage.data()+used; }
  size_t size() const { return used; }
  bool empty() const { return !used; }
  T& front() { return *begin(); }
  T const& front() const { return *begin(); }
  T& back() { return *std::prev(end()); }
  T const& back() const { return *std::prev(end()); }

  capped_array( std::initializer_list<T> il ):
    capped_array(il.begin(), il.end() )
  {}
};
```

the goal here is simple.  Create a stack based data type that stores a bunch of `T`s, up to a cap, and can handle having fewer.

Now we replace your `std::initializer_list` with:

```
auto get_foos = [=] (Switch ss) -> capped_array<int,3> {
    switch (ss) {
        case Switch_1:
            return {foo_1, foo_2, foo_3};
        case Switch_2:
            return {foo_4, foo_5};
        case Switch_3:
            return {foo_6, foo_7};
        default:
            throw std::logic_error("invalid switch");
    }
};
```

and your code works.  The free store is not used (no heap allocation).

A more advanced version would use an array of uninitialized data and manually construct each `T`.

Comment: You see, this very thing can be done using `std::vector/std::set/std::list` instead of `capped_array`. The useful property of `std::initializer_list` is that is can be used to initialize each of them (`std::vector/std::set/std::list`) alike. Just `std::<something> foo = get_foos(Switch_1);`. This is just a matter of convenience, the prettiness I wanted to have in my code.

Comment: @GreenScape I thought you where trying to avoid the free store (a needless memory allocation on the heap).  Creating a type that can be used to construct nearly arbitrary containers is easy -- just overload `template<class C>operator C()` with an extra SFINAE test that it can be constructed via `(iterator, iterator)`.  This is why posting motivation in your question (if only as an aside) is useful.

Comment: you see, `template<class C>operator C()` only enables easy copy initialization. For instance, if I have a `std::set<int> a = ...;` and later I want to insert more values to this container, with a `std::initializer_list` this can be done in very clean manner: `a.insert(get_foos(Switch_1))`. But if return value of a `get_foos()` is not an initializer list things get pretty messy. You have to call `get_foos()` before insert and store the result in some kind of aux variable, that is not very readable when you have to call `get_foos()` many times in a row.

Comment: @GreenScape Then implement `C +concat= X` or `concat( C, X )` with proper overloads.  On the left we detect if we are a sequence or associative container (sequence get `insert( end(c), s, f )`, associative get `insert( s, f )` if you really want this.  Or define different operations for associative containers and sequence containers (easier, as less mess around with `insert` overload and detection, which gets really messy).  Admittedly at this point it gets harder than the simple one above.  But `initializer_list` just doesn't work, so...

Comment: yeah, I just wanted a simple solution, it seemed possible but alas, not very likely for C++ as it is, it yields UB  :( So what's left is to use not so convenient but simple solution. In my case it's `std::set`. Thanks!

Comment: @GreenScape `std::vector` would be superior to `std::set`, because in contrast `std::vector` does not enforce a sort order that you clearly do not need (otherwise you wouldn't have been considering `std::initializer_list`) and does give contiguous elements.

Comment: @underscore_d actually, I do need a `std::set`, as seen in the OP: `std::set<int> foos = get_foos(Switch_1);`. The reason why I wanted to return `std::initializer_list` is because it is abstract, ie can be used to initialize a lot of other containers. But alas, it is not so simple.