# What is the lifetime of the array underlying a std::initializer_list?

Tags: c++, debugging, release, initializer-list

Following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29074955/1098041

I have a curious behavior.

In Debug I get the expected output, however in release (I'm using mingw on windows) I get garbage in the `test` fonction.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

template <class T>
struct array
{
    T     *ptr;
    size_t len;

    array() { clear(); }
    array( T *p, size_t l ) { assign(p,l); }

    inline void clear() { ptr=nullptr; len=0; }
    inline void assign( T *p, size_t l ) { ptr=p; len=l; }

    inline T& operator[] ( size_t i ) const { return ptr[i]; }
};

template <class T>
inline array<const T> wrap( std::initializer_list<T> lst )
    { return array<const T>( lst.begin(), lst.size() ); }


void test( int a, int b, int c )
{
    auto ar = wrap({a,b,c});
    std::cout<< ar[1] << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    auto a = wrap({1,2,3});
    std::cout<< a[2] << std::endl;

    test(1,2,3);
}
```

Output in debug :

```
3
3
```

Output in release:

```
3
2686868 // some garbage.
```

Can anyone explain to me how debug/release mode influences the lifetime of the initializer_list underlying array ?
Or provide some other explanation for this behavior.

Comment: Perhaps related to [Strange values in a lambda returning initializer_list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28318799/1708801)

Comment: I initially created this question because I found an odd behaviour that contradicted the accepted answer here that is linked in the question, and I was asked to provide a minimal example to reproduce my behaviour. i initially though this was a separate issue, but it appears that the answer to the 2 questions are contradictory. What now ? moderator please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  auto a = wrap({1,2,3});
```

The lifetime of the `initializer_list` (and its underlying array) ends at the end of that expression, so `a` contains a dangling pointer.

That means `std::cout<< a[2]` has undefined behaviour. Similarly for the code in `test`, `std::cout <<`a[1]` is also undefined behaviour.

> Can anyone explain to me how debug/release mode influences the lifetime of the initializer_list underlying array ? Or provide some other explanation for this behavior.

It's undefined behaviour.

Anything can happen.

In release mode the compiler optimizes things differently, so the layout of variables on the stack is different, so code with undefined behaviour might do something different. Or it might not.

This isn't even specific to `initializer_list`, you'd get similar undefined behaviour for *any* temporary object that you keep pointers into:

```
wrap( std::vector<int>(1, 1) );
```

Comment: So the fact that I get a valid output in `main`, but a invalid in `test` is UB ? Or does it has to do with the fact that in the first case the underlying array is constexpr and in the second it is built from variables ?

Comment: **Undefined behaviour means anything can happen!**  Undefined behaviour does not mean it always prints garbage! "I get the expected output" is one possible result, but that doesn't change the fact it's undefined and your program is buggy.

Comment: Yes ok fair enough. Doesn't really matter why one works and the other doesn't, it's UB. By the way this answer is in total contradiction with the accepted answer I linked in the question. I though this was a separate issue, but your answer seems to indicate it is not. Shall I delete this question ?

Comment: I have posted a new answer on the other question. I don't see any real need to delete this question, but it's up to you.

Comment: I've flagged it to the moderator. They'll do what htey think is right.

Comment: Situation seems to have been cleared on the other side but I can't delete this question.

Comment: Why does he have a dangling pointer? He copies the data from the initializer list with `array<const T>( lst.begin(), lst.size() );`.

Comment: @0x499602D2, where do you see any copying take place?

Comment: @JonathanWakely Sorry, I thought that was an iterator range and he was copying.