# static std::map<int, std::initializer_list<int>> data may corrupted in GCC 12

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

Test code:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <map>

const int *gIniListPtr = nullptr;

int fun(int n) {
  if (n == 0) return 0;
  int arr[1024];
  printf("write %p - %p\n", arr, arr + 1024);
  if (gIniListPtr >= arr && gIniListPtr < arr + 1024) {
    std::cout << "BUG!!!!!" << std::endl;
  }
  for (auto &i : arr) {
    i = rand();
  }
  std::sort(arr, arr + 1024);
  return arr[0] + fun(n - 1);
}

void printInfo() {
  static std::map<int, std::initializer_list<int>> m = {{0, {0}}, {1, {0, 1}}, {2, {0, 1, 2}}};
  printf("&iniList: %p\n", m[2].begin());
  gIniListPtr = m[2].begin();
  for (int n : m[2]) {
    std::cout << n << "  ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  srand(0);
  printInfo();
  fun(3);
  printInfo();
  return 0;
}
```

- Use GCC 8:

```
$ /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin/g++ --std=c++17 -O3 test.cpp && ./a.out
&iniList: 0x401c28
0  1  2
write 0x7ffdf7932bc0 - 0x7ffdf7933bc0
write 0x7ffdf7931b90 - 0x7ffdf7932b90
write 0x7ffdf7930b60 - 0x7ffdf7931b60
&iniList: 0x401c28
0  1  2
```

Works as expect.

- Use GCC 12:

```
$ /opt/rh/devtoolset-12/root/usr/bin/g++ --std=c++17 -O3 test.cpp && ./a.out
&iniList: 0x7ffd33088b10
2  1  2
write 0x7ffd33087b60 - 0x7ffd33088b60
BUG!!!!!
write 0x7ffd33086b20 - 0x7ffd33087b20
write 0x7ffd33085ae0 - 0x7ffd33086ae0
&iniList: 0x7ffd33088b10
2  2084420925  2086206725
```

```
$ /opt/rh/devtoolset-12/root/usr/bin/g++ --std=c++17 -O0 test.cpp && ./a.out
&iniList: 0x7ffd53479248
0  1  2
write 0x7ffd53478270 - 0x7ffd53479270
BUG!!!!!
write 0x7ffd53477220 - 0x7ffd53478220
write 0x7ffd534761d0 - 0x7ffd534771d0
&iniList: 0x7ffd53479248
2118421993  2118801173  2130794395
```

Do not works as expect, and `-O0`/`-O3` gives the different results.

---

In GCC 8, the `initializer_list` in `map` is allocated in the read-only data area. However, in GCC 12, it is allocated on the stack area and can be overwritten by other function calls.

---

I wonder if it's a bug in GCC or if my code is ill-formed or undefined?

Comment: You cannot use initializer lists like this. They cannot be stored, and should  only to be used in constructors. A `std::map<int,std::vector<int>>` might be more appropriate here. Also your code has more of a "C" than a "C++" flavor  ("C" style arrays, printf, pointer arithmetic etc).

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior. `std::initializer_list` doesn't own the actual elements. Roughly, it's a pair of pointers into a temporary array. So you stuff your map full of dangling pointers.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29077288/4885321