# How to write a function that returns a variadic template? Is that even right thing to do?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
template <typename... Args>
Args... func3()   // error here -> Syntactical failure at Args...
{
    return (1,2,3,4,5,6);
}

struct sample
{
    template <typename... Args>
    sample(Args... args) {}
};

sample s(func3());
```

I get a compilation error upon running this piece of code. Is this fixable? If not, how can i re-write?

Comment: Do you mean to return a `std::tuple<Args...>`?

Comment: For sequences of elements of the same type, I'd prefer using `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what you actually want to achieve, but it looks like you want to return a tuple of values of possible different types. There is a `std::tuple` which represents exactly this:

```
auto func3()
{
    return std::make_tuple(1,2,3,4,5,6);
}

struct sample
{
    template <typename... Args>
    sample(std::tuple<Args...>  args) {}
};

sample s(func3());
```

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for the hint. I sometimes forget that C++ does not infer return types from the context. You can fix it by declaring func3 to return `auto` because the compiler then infers the return type from the function body. I don't know if this is what the OP has in mind. Otherwise, you have to pass the types as template arguments as you showed in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need provide more info, but in some cases look into [initializer_list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/initializer_list/initializer_list/).

```
#include <initializer_list>

std::initializer_list<int> foo() {
    return {1,2,3,4,5};
}
```

And if you need some type independency, you can implement some Variants struct like: [QVariant](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html), [boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/any.html), [boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/variant.html)

But be aware of lifetime of [initializer_list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318799/strange-values-in-a-lambda-returning-initializer-list).